# Многопоточность на стороне сервера

Tags: c#, асинхронность, многопоточность, tpl

Клиент подключается к серверу, после подключения клиенту каждые 30 секунд происходит отправка данных. Для примера, подключаются 100 клиентов. Нужно обработать каждого и отправить всем необходимые данные. При этом необходим контроль. При отключении пользователя, для примера, останавливать поток и освобождать память...
И тут передо мной встал выбор, какие технологии использовать ?
TPL, Threads, Await Async. 
Просто чем дальше я начинаю читать про многопоточность, про плюсы и минусы тех или иных подходов в реализации, тем больше я запутываюсь во всем.
Посоветуйте, что мне использовать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильное решение не очевидно, пробуйте использовать технологии в порядке уменьшения степени абстракции.

Сначала async/await, если нужен более низкоуровневый контроль, то TPL, если и этот вариант контроля не подходит, переходите к потокам и AutoResetEvent'ам, дальше опускайтесь на уровень операционной системы и примитивов наподобие `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

Скорее всего, для вашей задачи вполне подойдёт async/await.

Comment: думаю опускаться до уровня операционной системы будет лишним ) Спасибо за совет.