# Алгоритм обработки задач/Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, async-await

[Предыдущий вопрос по данный тематике.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296103/c-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)
Насколько я понимаю, `Task<T>` выполняются асинхронно и можно контролировать каждую из запущенных задач, используя `async/await`. Если не использовать `await`, они выполняются все одновременно или поочередно?
Т.к при подлкючении клиента к серверу, мне нужно будет передавать данные из БД, клиенту, только пока он подключен, у меня возникла некоторая сложность с созданием алгоритма работы.
Вот код таймера, который каждые 30с передает клиенту данные из БД:

```
            AddTimer(() => PlayerIO.BigDB.Load("Users", clientId, delegate(DatabaseObject databaseObject)
            {
                var rec = databaseObject.GetObject("Recources");
                var al = rec.GetInt("Aluminium");

                player.Send(Message.Create("message", al));
            }), 30000);
```

Все это дело выполняется при кодключении клиента в методе `UserJoined(...){}`.
Т.к нужно обрабатывать каждого клиента отдельно, пришла идея, сделать все таким образом:

- клиент подключается
- создается новая задач с запуском таймера и с каждым новым клиентом интервал передачи данных увеличивается на какое то время
- задача добавляется в список
- клиент покидает игру
- останавливаем и удаляем задачу из списка (как отлавливать статус завершения у конкретной задачи ?)

**UPD:**
Обьясню поточнее на счет того что должно происходить и происходит на сервере. Есть два метода, которые срабатывают при подключении и отключении пользователя от сервера : UserJoined, UserLeft. Когда пользователь подключается, создается задача которая должна выполнять метод/таймер (AddTimer), который считает по формуле, например: х=х+2 записывает в БД и отсылает пользователю через определенный интервал времени. При отключении пользователя от сервера, думаю должен передаваться флаг, CancellationToken, если не путаю и отключать задачу. Но, допустим у нас есть список, в который добавляются все задачи, которые на данный момент выполняются, как отключать задачу, которая принадлежит конкретному пользователю ?
Как бы вы организовали все это ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, а что сложного? Вы же всё описали сами:

```
// модель
async Task RunUser(CancellationToken ctx)
{
    var delay = Timespan.FromSeconds(30);
    for (int x = 0; ; x += 2)
    {
        ctx.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await PutValueToDatabase(x, ctx).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ctx.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(delay, ctx).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

// VM
async void OnUserEntered(UserInfo info)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    info.CancellationSource = cts;
    try
    {
        await model.RunUser(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException)
    {
    }
}

async void OnUserExited(UserInfo info)
{
    info.CancellationSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: т.е если я сделаю модель так: http://pastebin.com/Jx60K1rv
данный код будет выполняться каждые 30 секунд ?

Comment: @Sier: в принципе, да, 30 секунд + время на работу с базой. Я бы однако зарефакторил так, чтобы получить асинхронный интерфейс у базы. Плюс база сама должна решать, в каком потоке ей работать.

Итого: http://pastebin.com/M7TJ4rWN (обратите внимание на scheduler у базы).

Comment: @VladD, "зарефакторить", под этим вы имеете ввиду переопределить метод bigDb.Load(); или в исходном классе BigDB сделать данную поправку ?

Comment: @Sier: Ну, я бы оставил синхронный метод для случая, если он кому-то нужен, и выдал асинхронную обёртку `bigDb.LoadAsync`. Посмотрите по коду, там несколько мелких правок. Ну и вполне возможно, база данных хочет, чтобы с ней разговаривали только из одного потока.

А ещё, отсылка сообщения клиенту должна тоже быть асинхронной.

Comment: @VladD, просто дело в том, что все методы работы с БД предоставляются в библиотеке, к которым я не имею доступа, кроме использования этих методов, поэтому, наверное, придется использовать предыдущий способ. На счет синхронной отправки данных клиенту - отдельное, спасибо. Единственное, что еще пришло в голову так это хранить этот загруженный обьект на всем протяжении сессии и использовать его для всех запросов клиента. Есть ли в этом смысл ?

Comment: @Sier: Ну, напишите тогда обёртку над базой данных, которая пусть использует библиотеку внутри.

Насчёт хранения загруженного объекта выясните, идиоматично ли это в вашей базе данных — например, может быть, это оставит открытым соединение, а это может быть не так хорошо. Здесь я не специалист.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за помощь! Много нового узнал из ответов, многому научился. Но узнал я грустную правду, долго мне не отвечали на офф.форуме этой библиотеки, оказывается что у них эти методы изначально поддерживают асинхронность. Но когда возникла ошибка загрузки .dll на сайт, я чуть не бросил заниматься с этой библиотекой и решил попробовать новую: lidgren-network. В любом случае теперь обе буду испытывать )

Comment: @Sier: вот и отлично — значит, у вас будет опыт работы с _двумя_ библиотеками!